# Why session is clearing while we clear cookies in the browser?

Tags: php

I am doing a project in PHP. I have a small doubt in cookies and session.

Here is my doubt.

1. Cookies are saved on browser side.
2. Session is saved on server side.

**If we clear cookies in the browser why session is also getting clear.**

As per conditions cookies are saved in browser side. And session are saved in server side.
If we clear cookies in browser how the session which is stored in server is also clearing.

Kindly clarify this...

thanks in advance...

Comment: Isn't a `php` session just a `cookie`? :s

Answer (score 4):

The server uses cookies for tracking the user's session. The specific cookie we are looking for is **PHPSESSID** which is the tracking cookie.

Thus, if you delete this cookie, the server loses track of the client and hence it will be terminated.

Here is some reference.

http://oreilly.com/pub/a/php/excerpt/webdbapps_8/index.html?page=2

Answer (score 0):

PHP allows for use of cookies or database with session storing.  If you're using cookies only, this is typically what's causing that.  You can solve that by using a database-session, and using via querystring/trans id.

Hope this helps.

Edit to include missed piece Maerlyn pointed out.

Comment: That's incorrect. If you delete the session cookie, the server will lose track of you, regardless of how you store session data on the server.

Comment: Not necessarily.  You can maintain via querystring, application.  You don't have to use a cookie.  I can provide documentation if you'd like.

Comment: I know of the trans sid config setting. Quote from you: "You can solve that by using a database-session.", that's plain incorrect.

Answer (score -3):

> The server uses Cookies for tracking
>   the user's session. The specific
>   cookie we are looking for is
>   PHPSESSIONID which is the tracking
>   cookie.
>   Blockquote

As Adarsh R said

How ever you can prevent this if you save the sessions into a database table using session_id
and serialize the session this is for users that can't change the php.ini

EDIT

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$browser_string = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$session_id = session_ID();
$session = serialize($_SESSION);
```

The DB code is an exercise for the reader.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `sessions` WHERE `ip`='".$ip."' AND `browser_string`='".$browser_string ."'";
```

Hopefully you can work it out from that.

Comment: That's incorrect. If you delete the session cookie, the server will lose track of you, regardless of how you store session data on the server.

Comment: yea use IP's and browser string! i was telling him how he could save the session_id and data in it not what you need to do.,

Comment: Assume a corporate environment, multiple machines on the same IP, same corporate windows image, all using IE6. How do you tell them apart? Also: assume an ISP, that has multiple outside addresses, and when a client request something, chooses the one with the least load - meaning the outside IP is changing from request to request. How do you link them together? Your solution is flawed.

Comment: not that good for a live production environment: dynamic ips .

Comment: Yea so are SESSIONS thats the reason where answering the question

Comment: @poelinca ERR go learn how dynamic IP's work (its called a lease time most router auto renew the same IP at the end of the lease time) so most of the time you have to force it in some way not paying your bill, turning off your rooter you will never change ip while your currently connected and using it the ISP will send down a new lease time.

Comment: a 20 seconds power failure will casue me to relogin into you're app , am i right or wrong ? or if i whant for example to configure some port forwarding on my router , that will again need a router restart witch will cause you're app to loose track of me and probably my work too .

Comment: yea but if your that cleaver Why TF would you whipe your cookies when your know what they do only idiots who follow security software to the letter do that FFS not even NORTON tells you to remove cookies any more.

Comment: @Barkermn01 - Knowledge does not always mean _professionalism_ , see my edits to your question as an example.

Comment: @Tim Post, what i'm arguing here is that that answer is supposedly point less you got get rid of the data or it can affect multiple users

And what im trying to say is its allways posible the Web is not windows there will allways be ways around stuff allways you want to do it properly build an application where they login to that it saves there info to there computer and auto sends that to the server and the server send Javascript calls to right data back to the client o wait no one would use it coz the don't trust you. 

INTERNET IS NOT PERFECT AND CAN NOT BE

Comment: please calm down a bit , i was just pointing some scenarios when you're code will fail to work just as if somebody would delete they'r cookies , however router restart is more usual than cookie deleteing ( in my opinion atleast ) .

Comment: poelinca i know what your on about as a server administrator though i have to dissagree a router restart means down time should not do it though the IT dept first thing that say with a web problem is to whipe cookies ppl